# How to concatenate a specific column from several file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data file `A.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A SDF
254 20B
261 40A
267 20B
```

`B.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A
254 20B
261 40A
267 20B SLT
```

`C.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A
254 20B
261 40A MGG
267 20B
```

And I want to concatenate all the file into one, knowing that the only column that is different between all the file is the column `mutation`. The result expected is :

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A SDF
254 20B
261 40A MGG
267 20B SLT
```

So far I tried :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{klos[NR]=$3; next} $3==""{$3=klos[FNR]} 1' *.tsv > output.tsv
```

But it didn't works. Do you have a way to do that ? Thanks

PS: Here is a sample test, in my real condition I have more than 3 files. But like the example, there are not two file with the same thing in the `mutation` column.

Comment: You say there are no two files with the same data in the `mutation` field. What about two files that have _different_ data in that field?  You are only showing us examples where exactly one file has data in that field for a particular row.  Also, are all `id`-`clade` pairs represented in all files, as you show?

Comment: For example, for the first sample line (first line after the header), only one file have something in the `mutation` column. For the other column; I use the same command for generate all the file so only the  `mutation` column differ from one file to another

Comment: I've edit my question do take in count that the line with no field in the `mutation` column also need to be print

Comment: One should never under specify or oversimplify a pbm. Now I'm not sure how many fields your files have. Most of the time the approach taken are a very strong function of the specs. So they must reflect the actual data.O otherwise be prepared for lots of iterations before converging to a working solution.The time saved in cooking up artificial data is more than used up in getting the solution to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `paste` then processing its output with `awk`:

```
paste file[ABC].tsv |\
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" } { for(i=3; i<=NF; i+=3) if($i"")break; print $1, $2, $i }'
```

the used condition `if($i"")break` is to break the for-loop (double quotes is used to force awk to do string comparison) as soon as first non-empty field was found, then later just print fields #1, #2 and that non-empty field which was found previously in field #i.

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
(NR == FNR) || ($3 != "") {
    fnr2rec[FNR] = $0
}
FILENAME == ARGV[ARGC-1] {
    print fnr2rec[FNR]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv
id      clade   mutation
243     40A     SDF
254     20B
261     40A     MGG
267     20B     SLT
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work (if you don't mind the results in reverse).

```
[root@SE ~]# awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} { if($3>0) { print }}' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -ru
```

I am sure there may be a simpler way to achieve this, as I am still relatively new to `awk`.

What I am doing is simply printing all 3 files and removing all rows in mutation without characters. The `sort -u` pipe then removes all duplicates. The `-r` flag reverses the order.

```
[root@SE ~]# awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} { if($3>0) { print }}' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -ru
id  clade   mutation
267 20B SLT
261 40A MGG
254 20B SLT
243 40A SDF
```

@Quasimodo has simplified this. Thank you.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} (FNR>1 || NR==1) && $3' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv
```

This will print a line if it is either the very first line processed (i.e. the header of the first input file), or any line which is *not* the header, but contains a non-empty 3rd field. It works because a boolean expression outside of a rule block (`{ ... }`) that evaluates to "true" instructs `awk` to print the current line.

Comment: I've edit my question do take in count that the line with no field in the `mutation` column also need to be print

Comment: Just add a sort pipe.
awk '(NR==1 || FNR>1) { print }' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -uk3 | sort -r
`id  clade   mutation
267 20B SLT
261 40A MGG
254 20B
243 40A SDF`

Comment: @HatLess with the command of your last comment, the result is not good because it print also the line that don't have a field in a file but has in another one. Meaning that I end up with "just" a concatenation of the file

Comment: I am working with 3 files and the values that you provided. In my test, all 4 rows are returned with the one empty field in mutation.

Comment: @AdminBee Including that arguemnt (&& $3) will remove all empty results under mutation. I deliberately excluded it and instead used sort -k3 with the -u flag. There is also another piped sort with the reverse flag otherwise the heading shows up randomly in the middle of the rows.

Comment: @HatLess Ah, you are right!

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. My original scripts worked perfectly. Someone edited it to one that does not work and I do not know why. I am new so left the changes as I figured it was an admin. Here is the original if it helps `[root@SE ~]# awk '{ if($3>0) { print }}' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -ru`

Comment: And the original @Quasímodo edit that also worked `awk '(FNR>1 || NR==1) && $3 { print }' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv`

Comment: @EdMorton After the update, 2 further sort pipes were included so it can execute as expected, therefore giving the expected result as far as the data that has been provided is concerned. The updated code can be found in this comment section near the top.

`awk '(NR==1 || FNR>1) { print }' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -uk3 | sort -r`

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks, but I will leave it there for now not as a nicety, but because I think it may actually be relevant elsewhere.
The change may be appropriate in other shells but in my labs, it does not work. The change was only adding the field seperators `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` but this results in blank output.
For the field seperators to be valid, the code needs to change somewhat `awk -F"\t" '{ $3>0;  print }' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -uk3 | sort -r` or ` awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} { $3>0;  print }' A.tsv B.tsv C.tsv | sort -uk3 | sort -r` both work with the same output

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [Miller's nest verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs.html#nest), to **i**mplode **v**alues **a**cross **r**ecords:

```
$ mlr --tsv --ragged nest --ivar "" -f mutation {A..C}.tsv
id      clade   mutation
243     40A     SDF
254     20B
261     40A     MGG
267     20B     SLT
```

(assuming a shell that supports brace expansion). You can omit the `--ragged` input modifier if the missing `mutation` values are empty rather than absent. The empty nested-fs `""` means that if there *are* conflicting values they will be concatentated.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have experiment mlr and it generates some format issue. Also I need to use tool that are native for CentOS machine (i.e awk, grep, sort, python ...)

Answer (score 0):

One approach using the bash commandline utilities can be:

```
## initialization 
ref= tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) cn=3

for f in ./*.tsv;do
  : ${ref:="$f"}
 < "$f" cut -f"$cn" > "$tmpdir/$f"
done

paste <(cut -f-"$((cn-1))" "$ref") "$tmpdir"/* |
tr -s '\t' |
sed -ne "1s/\t/\n/$cn" -e 's/\t*$//;P'
```

Results:

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A SDF
254 20B
261 40A MGG
267 20B SLT
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code but I'm not sure if I have fully understand.
If with my real data the column `mutation` is in $47 , what part of your code need to be change apart from `-f3`

Comment: I have included the column number as a variable `$cn` now.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    m[$1,$2] == "" { m[$1,$2] = $3 }
    END { for (k in m) { split(k,a,SUBSEP); print a[1],a[2],m[k] } }' [ABC].tsv |
sort -n
```

This keeps track of the `mutation` for a specific `id` and `clade` in the associative array `m` (indexed by `id` and `clade`). The mutation for a particular key is updated if a non-empty value hasn't yet been associated with that particular key.

At the end, we loop over all keys in `m`, break them apart into `id` and `clade` (in `a[1]` and `a[2]` respectively) and output the corresponding values.  We need to sort the output at the end since the ordering of keys coming out of a hash is random.